# 2 sites sharing one user table

Tags: 7, users

How can I make 2 Drupal websites share the same user table so when a user is logged in on one they are automatically logged in on the other?

Answer (score 5):

Your question seems to be all over the place. However, the [Bakery Single Sign-On System](http://drupal.org/project/bakery) module sounds like what you need.

> Bakery provides a "single sign on" feature for Drupal based sites that are on the same second-level domain (i.e. example.com, subsite.example.com, subsite2.example.com). It could also provide support for any other website that implements the same web cookie, xmlrpc, and POST methods.
>
> This module started at the 2009 Drupal.org redesign sprint in San Francisco as a way to manage single sign-ons across *.drupal.org infrastructure.
>
> Read the [bakery documentation](http://drupal.org/node/567410) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr Try using the [Domain](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module suite. I allows you to run a site that "pretends" to be more than on domain, and helps you with relevant access rules and content sharing.

My experience with sharing tables is that you are in for a world of pain. I've tried it twice in the past and it has had various odd effects, due to various modules becoming confused. I no longer remember any specifics though, but if I did it today, I would take my own advice from above. :)