# How would i redirect a user after registration to his subdomain site

Tags: 7, users, subsites

I want to redirect a user after successful registration `maindomain.com` to open his site in a `new tab`.

His site `url` will look like this `newuser.maindomain.com`. (username.maindomain)

Any Suggestions?

Comment: How are you setting up/creating the subdomains?

Comment: @PatrickKenny: i am using domain rules module to create sub domains. using rules i create new domains, when user registers i am creating like user-name.domain.com.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) again to do the redirect.

On Event **Drupal is initializing** or **User has logged in** add a condition if you need that (eg **check that user role is not anoymous**) and then add an Action of **Redirect**. In there use some php for the redirect path using the global variable $user (you may need some formation also if the username has spaces).

Notice that you must **run this Rule after the rule that creates the subdomain**. Or you can simply add the redirect action on the same domain_rules rule after the component that creates the subdomain.

You must also have a [common user database along sites](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/26893/12163) (domain and subdomain). The [Bakery module](https://drupal.org/project/bakery) is a good option here.

Comment: A walkthrough of how RULES implement it can be found at http://drupalize.me/videos/login-redirects, where it also deals with the small bug in the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

i feel you have to use SSO for authentication among multiple domains, check this [bakery module](https://drupal.org/project/bakery)!