# How to sync users profiles and user tables in 2 drupal sites

Tags: users, multi-sites, database

I have a website with 14K registered users. There is new section of that website which has been developed as a separate Drupal installation. The users in the old website should be able to login with their username and password to the new site.

My questions are :

1. is there a way to connect new site "user registration/login/forget
   password" features with the old one?
2. Should i sync the databases all
   the time? Or when the new user registers, his information is added
   in to new and old site ( and Vice Versa)

What is the best practice in such cases.

thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 sites sharing one user table](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26893/2-sites-sharing-one-user-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can sync Drupal accounts.

1. Using [Drupal OpenID-Single-Sign on (OMniauth)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2177681) which very common method for the big organisation who manage a number of drupal/websites. more on that please refer to [Comparison of Single Sign On (SSO) Modules](https://groups.drupal.org/node/182004)
2. You can also look into [Account Sync module](https://www.drupal.org/project/account_sync) which I haven't tested myself yet and it has a very limited number of site "130" reported using it so you better be careful with it. The module provide basic single sign-on support.
3. The other way will be to export users from sites using [User Export module](https://www.drupal.org/project/users_export). then use [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to import site. You can use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to to export and import users between both sites, probably by running crone on both sites in sequence.
4. Take look into [Bakery Single Sign-On System](https://www.drupal.org/project/bakery), which is useful single sin-on for the sites that based on the same second-level domain "example.come, test.example.com".
5. [Domain Access module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) which suite of modules that provide tools for running group of affiliated sites from on drupal installation and single shared database. The module allows you to share users.

Comment: great thanks for the information. I will start checking all of them. But does it matter if i am hosting both sites on two different hosting.?

Comment: @brainHax your welcome, If your using two different hosting then Bakery Single Sign-On System is not useful at all, I recommend you look into Drupal OpenID-Single-Sign on (OMniauth) which is more standard and well recognized. Don't forget to accept the the answer as solution if it is useful.